# Aura Pass Input text Field to Apex

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have a TextField(AboutMe__c) that I am displaying on an Aura page. The user will write stuff and when they hit submit I want to save whatever they typed to Quote.AboutMe__c field. When I debug this AboutMe__c is coming up as null when I type something and hit the button. Any Ideas as to why?

Aura

```
<div class="slds-clearfix slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning:input class="About_Me" aura:id="AboutMe" min="0" step="1" 
                                    label="AboutMe" type="text"
                                    value="{!v.quote.AboutMe__c}" required="true" />
                </div>
</div>
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-4">
                <div class="slds-clearfix slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="{!$Label.c.OnSubmit}" 
                                    onclick="{!c.onSubmit}" />
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.onCancel}" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
 onSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
     
       var AboutMe = component.get('v.quote.AboutMe__c');
       console.log("ManageQuote - v.quote.AboutMe__c value:", AboutMe);
        

},
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because the attribute is of the wrong type. The following should work:

```
<aura:attribute name="quote" type="Quote" default="{}" />
```

You can use an sObject of any type, or you can specify the type of `Map`, which also behaves correctly. Using something like `Object` or `String` won't work as you expect.

Comment: i change my line to <aura:attribute name="quote" type="Quote__c" default="{}" /> and it didnt work

Comment: @CodeMonger We'd need to see more code. It'd be easier if I could copy paste. I did test this in my org, it's works fine.